# How to redesign Google calendar create event page using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I am trying to develop a chrome which re-designs Google calendar create event page by adding/removing few elements. Google seems to have obfuscated their CSS class names and element Ids making it difficult to identify a particular DOM element using javascript.

Is there a way to fetch DOM elements from Calendar page using JS?

Comment: There are only the standard DOM methods, there's no magic wand.

Comment: Ya, by standard DOM methods we can fetch, but they seem to have obfuscated their class names and I believe class names will keep changing over time rendering my piece of code broken over time. My question is, Is there a way around this?

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: the easier way would be to write your own page from scratch, with full control over it, and use the API in the background to interact with the calendar data.